# AngularJS - Dynamic element is not adding in link function

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mylist = ["rag", "VJ", "DK", "Lol", "Mangal"];
});


app.directive("myDirective", function($compile){
    return {
        template : "<div>SWESH</div>",
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var newel = $compile('<select id="customerDD" ng-options="item for item in mylist"></select>')(scope);
            element.append(newel);
        }

    }
});
```

Trying to add dynamic elements in angular custom directive, it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options`

```
 var template='<select> <option ng-repeat="item in myList">{{item}}</option></select>'
 var linkFn = $compile(template);
 var content = linkFn(scope);
 element.append(content);
```

checkout the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/getebin/rpjacmy2/